# Team Explorer Builds doesn't show build definitions, says "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I've recently moved from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012 (version: 11.0.51106.01 Update 1). In Team Explorer -> Builds, I added some build definitions to my favorites. Now, when I open Team Explorer -> Builds, I don't see any build definitions, and instead I see an error:
`An item with the same key has already been added.`

Why does this happen?
How can I resolve this issue?
I suppose I could somehow delete those favorite build definitions, but where are they stored?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a known issue with TFS2012.

**Cause:** When a favorite build definition has more than one build queued (say, a gated and private build), VS2012 will create a blank favorite build, and then issue this error when it reloads the favorites.

**Fix:** None yet AFAIK.

**Workaround :** Edit `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\FavoritesStore\<GUID>.xml`:

- Temporary workaround: Remove the `<FavoriteItem Name="" ...` line. However, VS2012 will create it again.
- Permanent workaround: Remove the relevant build definitions from the favorites.

Some ([blog post](http://henrywrites.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/tfs-vs2012-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added/), [Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778725/tfs-2012-agile-6-1-template-problem-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added), [Connect bug 2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779288/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-from-builds-view-of-team-explorer)) suggest removing the TFS cache, but that didn't work.